# How to change OptionButton fill color in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I change the fill color of an Excel OptionButton in VBA?
[image]

Comment: you cannot change the black dot if that's what youre trying to do

Comment: I am trying to change the Fill color. The background color of the OptionButton.

Comment: try this in vba `RadioButton1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)`

Comment: That is not valid VBA. Getting erros. But I found the answer by accident after googling your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer by accident thanks to your comments. :D

```
ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("MyOptionButton").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
```